# Qmailrocks installation error on CentOS 6.6

Tags: centos-6, qmail

I've managed to install qmail-1.03 using the qmailrocks procedure on CentOS 6.6.

When I telnet to port 25, I get an error in the qmail log below:

[root@www qmail]# telnet domain.com 25
Trying XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX...
Connected to domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

@40000000550795d1198e8c94 /var/qmail/bin/qmail-smtpd: error while loading shared libraries: libkeyutils.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem.  You have a line in `/service/qmail-smtpd/run` that reads something like

```
softlimit -m 30000000
```

to set a memory limit.  Simply raise that limit.